# Appium - Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure

Tags: java, ios, macos, appium, appium-ios

I've upgraded to Appium 1.6.5 and every time I launch appium I get following error

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not
>   start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote
>   server or browser start-up failure.

I'm using following
Appium 1.6.5
IntelliJ
Every time I run the script I get following error - Full Log

```
package Steps;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.AutomationName;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class iOSDependency {
public static AppiumDriver driver;
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone 6");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "iOS");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "10.2");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, AutomationName.IOS_XCUI_TEST);
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APPIUM_VERSION, "1.6.5");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "/Users/sanganit/Downloads/preprod.ipa");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "iOS");
    driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4273/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Thread.sleep(30000);
  }
    }
```

Comment: Please add a question.

Comment: Why am I getting this error and how can I over come this issue?

Comment: please enter error logs in your question which you get in appium console... also you dont need a BROWSER_NAME capability for launching app...... please check if this is an emulator build or not, to double check, this is the build path "/Users/`whoami`/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/preprod.app"